# Histogram matching in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, digital-image-processing, sentinel-1, histogram, sar

Does anyone know if there is a more GEE-friendly way of achieving this? I'm experimenting with S1 SAR image histogram matching in GEE and was wondering if foremost the code can be improved. Read [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) that the use of for-loops and `getInfo()` calls should be discouraged due to the overhead it brings with transferring data downstream to the browser and upstream to the server.

Here's the code:

```
/**
* Function that returns a normalized image using unitScale()
* @param image the image object
* @param band the band to select
* @param aoi the area of interest for scoping the reducer
*/
function getNormalizedImage(image, band, aoi) {
  var redux = getReducedImage(image, ee.Reducer.minMax(), aoi);
  return image.unitScale(
    ee.Number(redux.get(band + '_min')),
    ee.Number(redux.get(band + '_max'))
  );
}

/**
 * Function wrapper for a reducer
 * @param image the image object
 * @param reducer the reducer to apply, see API docs
 * @param aoi the area of interest for scoping the reducer
 */
function getReducedImage(image, reducer, aoi) {
  return image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: reducer,
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
}

/**
 * Function that returns a histogram array object
 * @param image the image object
 * @param band the band to select
 * @param aoi the area of interest for scoping the reducer
 */
function getHistogram(image, band, aoi) {
  var redux = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(256, 1),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  var histoDict = ee.Dictionary(redux.get(band)).get('histogram');
  return histoDict;
}

/**
 * Function that returns a cumulative distribution function 
 * as a list object
 * @param image the image object
 * @param band the band to select
 * @param aoi the area of interest for scoping the reducer
 */
function getCDF(image, band, aoi) {
  var histoArr = ee.List(getHistogram(image.multiply(255), band, aoi));
  var len = histoArr.length().subtract(1);
  var nPixels = ee.Array(histoArr).accum(0).toList().get(len);
  var CDF = ee.Array(histoArr).accum(0).divide(nPixels).multiply(len);
  return [CDF.round().toList(), len];
}

/**
 * Function that returns a source image that has been 
 * matched with the target's image histogram using
 * the remap function from Earth Engine
 * @param imageR the source image object
 * @param imageZ the target image object
 * @param bandR the source band to select
 * @param bandZ the target band to select
 * @param aoi the area of interest for scoping the reducer
 */
function matchHistogram(imageR, imageZ, bandR, bandZ, aoi) {
  var cdfR = getCDF(imageR, bandR, aoi);
  var cdfZ = getCDF(imageZ, bandZ, aoi);
  var lenR = cdfR[1];
  var lenZ = cdfZ[1];
  var map = [];

  var cdfR0 = cdfR[0].getInfo();
  var cdfZ0 = cdfZ[0].getInfo();

  for (var r = 0; r < cdfR0.length; r++) {
    var max = Infinity;
    var min = 0;
    for (var z = 0; z < cdfZ0.length; z++) {
      var diff = Math.pow(cdfZ0[z] - cdfR0[r], 2);
      if (diff < max) {
        max = diff;
        min = z;
      }
    }
    map.push(min);
  }

  var seq = ee.List.sequence(0, lenR);
  var imageM = imageR.multiply(lenR).round().remap(seq, map, 0).divide(lenR);
  return imageM.select(['remapped'], [bandR]);
}
```

`getInfo()` is being called in the functions `matchHistogram` <s>and `getCDF`</s>.

**UPDATE:** I've managed to improve `getCDF` by removing the `getInfo()` call there, `matchHistogram` seems a bit more tricky to solve.